# Is Koch fractal a real Jordan curve?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, plane-curves

Let $K\subset \mathbb{R^2}$ be the *Koch fractal*. We have by construction the injective and continuous map $S^1\rightarrow K$ that takes a finite arc length to infinity.

Do we have the inverse map $K\rightarrow S^1$, and is there any ambiguities with the Jordan curve theorem?

**EDIT**: This question came to my mind when I read Wikipedia about **wild arcs**: "*a wild arc is an embedding of the unit interval into 3-dimensional space not equivalent to the usual one in the sense that there does not exist an ambient isotopy taking the arc to a straight line segment*."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, try to prove the following fact: Any continuous bijective map from a compact space into a Hausdorff space is a homeomorphism.

Comment: I know that but it's still hard to believe!

Comment: Yes. I was considering the difficulties with "wild arcs" but apparently Koch fractal is completely unrelated when it comes to embeddings.